# Keyof object keys. Rename a key doesn't work?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm going to make a huge refactoring in my project for renaming dictionary keys. And I thought it will be easy with a refactoring feature in VSCode, but that feature doesn't work correctly for a such case. Let's say I want to rename the key in the dictionary object from "a" to "d", via rename feature a click f2 and expecting that everywhere where the key "a" was used in the `translation` function, that symbol will be renamed, but it doesn't happen, "a" key is keep staying and I've got only typescript error "Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"d" | "b" | "c"'"

Can anyone help me with any ideas on how to make it work? By the way I tried the same feature in WebStorm and it also doesn't work.

This is a small example of dictionary structure and translate function, for getting an idea

```
const dictionary = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

type Keys = keyof typeof dictionary;

function translate(key: Keys, dict: typeof dictionary) {
  return dict[key];
}

translate("a", dictionary);
```

Comment: Your example works for me in IntelliJ Idea: when I rename the property `a` in the `dictionary` constant, then the `"a"` parameter in the translate function call is also updated correctly.

Comment: wow, it is already something, I will try to download it, any specifics about how to do it correctly there? In webstorm I used, Refactor -> Rename. Is it correct?

Comment: just press F2 and rename it - I use IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2023.1.3 (and typescript 4,8,4), but AFAIK it should work in the same way in WebStorm..

Comment: Yeah, confirmed it wokrs, thank you, you saved a lot of my time

Comment: VS Code's TypeScript support pretty much just uses TypeScript itself. I'd suggest you [create a feature-request issue ticket about this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=Feature_request.md&title=). If you do, please [edit] your post to link to it.